# XPM "Updating Preview" not working for Page layout changes

Tags: experience-manager, updatepreview

I have been having “Update Preview” issues when making Component Presentation changes on a Page with XPM. I.E. adding/removing Component Presentations or changing the ordering. I have distilled my example down to a simple implementation.

## Setup

A single Schema with a simple text field.
Several Components were created based on this Schema.

A Component Template was created that is:

- linked to this Schema
- uses TBB layout based on the simplest Dreamweaver example found on docs.sdl.com
- uses the SDL Default TBB - Enable inline editing for content

A Page Template (HTML) was created that

- uses a simple Dreamweaver TBB to display all Component Presentations.
- uses the SDL Default TBB - Enable inline editing for Page

A Page based on that Page Template was created with several of the Component/Component Templates defined above included.

## Results

Now if I enter XPM and make a layout change (i.e. reorder the Components) I get the following results:

I get two success messages from the CM

- Saving All Changes
- All Changes have been saved

One Warning Message from the CM

- The preview for this Page is not up to date
- Your changes to this Page make an update of the Page preview necessary.

And one message echoed to the browser’s console (with a TCM URI correctly identifying the changed Page)

> Can't execute the command **"NotifyRequiredRepublishing"** on [tcm:84-99892]. Reason: **not enabled**.

At this point repeated presses of the “Update Page Preview”  produce no differences and repeat the Warning message.
(However: The Page in the CM has been changed (with the Component Presentations reordered) and the history has increased by a minor version number. If I “Finish editing” and republish my changes are correctly maintained.)

Any help with the updating of the Page preview would be appreciated.

Comment: Is your publisher configured for session preview? It looks like your configuration is not able to update the session preview database. CM functionalities like inserting new content, saving and publishing would still work. Can you run on DEBUG mode and also add the error from your cd_core log when you receive the above warning in the CME?

Comment: It appears that it was the configuration that was causing the error.  The underlying configuration was the responsibility of another team and after some experimenting basic XPM changes are now working!  Thanks Shiva!

Comment: Glad you were able to solve it!

Comment: To clean up the amount of unanswered questions on this site, can we request that you self-answer this question with your found solution and then accept that answer?

Comment: Absolutely splendid question, with the right level of detail. I'd like to second Bart, though - a good answer would help everyone, and as you found the solution yourselves, we'd appreciate the details.